# AngularJS: Why do I need a template in a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I read the [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), but still I wonder why one would need a template in a directive at all? Why isn't it possible to just have a partial?

Comment: To avoid downloading the partial when its code could be defined directly in the directive.

Comment: Directives are components. They should not load partials. For those tasks you use either ngView or ngInclude

Comment: I use 'template' when the template is a very small amount of html.  If it is more than one or two elements, I use 'templateUrl' with a partial for readability.

Comment: Thanks for your answers JBNizet, Crai Squire and @Dalorzo. I know that I can't load partials in components, but why can't I just not specify a template in the directive at all and just go with the partial? Feels like I'm missing a major point here.

Comment: I would say the answer you are looking for is 42....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a partial via the TemplateUrl property (instead of Template property). The partial can be a file that physically resides on the server or could reside in a script tag with type of 'text/ng-template'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mike Cheel. See comment above: Why can't I just not specify a template in the directive at all and just go with the partial?

Comment: Directives are used mainly as components or to augment existing directives. In both cases they are re-usable and encapsulate the logic required to accomplish its particular goal. Also, directives are where you want to manipulate the DOM from. If you jsut want to load some static page then a partial will work (although you will probably want to look at using the directive ngView).